# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list when upload to aws s3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-2.7, boto3

I am trying to create a script that will place a file inside a folder in the s3 bucket. Here's my code:

```py
AccountName = ["AWSAccountName"]

def upload_s3(AccountName,bucket,filename):
    dir = os.getcwd()
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    #prefix = 'folder_' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + "/" + filename
    prefix =  AccountName + 'folder_' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + "/" + filename
    #s3object = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=prefix)
    s3.upload_file(dir + '/' +filename, bucket, prefix)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_s3(AccountName, "ec2-idle-workspace-list","EC2_Idle_info_cpu_NetworkIn_NetworkOut.csv")
```

However, while running the script, it gives me the following error:

```py
 prefix =  AccountName + 'folder_' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + "/" + filename
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
[Pipeline] echo
script returned exit code 1
```

Comment: `AccountName = ["AWSAccountName"]` why is `AccountName` a list?

Comment: You should replace code like this: `dir + '/' +filename` with code like this: `os.path.join(dir, filename)`. Also you have a terminology issue: your variable `prefix` is not actually a prefix, it's a `key`.

Comment: Your upload is probably going to fail because it can't find `dir + '/' +filename`. That's because `dir` is your current working directory, not a subdirectory (with the same name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate `AccountName + 'folder_' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + "/" + filename` but AccountName is a list, not a string.

Replace `AccountName = ["AWSAccountName"]` with `AccountName = "AWSAccountName"`.

Or replace 
`AccountName + 'folder_' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + "/" + filename`
 With
 `AccountName[0] + 'folder_' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + "/" + filename`

Comment: why i am using a list because i am appending this value as key from a dictionary ```for key, value in AWS_ACC_DICT.items():
    if (int(value) == int(account_id)):
    AccountName.append(key)```

Comment: Then use AccountName[0] when concatenating. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Lior V. It actually worked out!!

Comment: If you need to (reverse) lookup account name from account ID then it might be better to have a (reverse) dict that maps account ID to account name and then simply use `acctdict[id]` to get the account name.